# A dirty limerick

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, limerick

What word is described by the following limerick?

> A place where the lions may roar?
>   A place you attend after four?
>   The usual sense
>   Will shortly commence
>   Exploding with colors galore!

I will accept the first answer that explains all the clues, including the one in the title.

---

Hint/clarification:

> For lines 4-5, you may wish to note when this riddle was posted and what [my location](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21402/dlosc) is.

Further clarification:

> "When" and "where" in the above hint are meant in a very general sense: think "what time of year" and "what continent."

Comment: Dang this is intense :P

Comment: this sounds like the knowledge tag may be applicable.

Comment: @micsthepick Hm... probably not? It's hard to say more without giving too much away, but "the usual sense," at least, is quite ordinary. There is a bit of a trick to the other clues, so upon further reflection, I have added the wordplay tag.

Comment: "When" as in time in Kansas city, right?

Comment: @ABcDexter In a sense, but probably not how you're thinking. I'll clarify more. :P

Comment: Does it happen to have any relation with rnfgre (rot13) ? I keep having a nagging feeling that it does but i cant even imagine how to connect it to the initial few lines

Comment: @casualcoder Only coincidentally, in that rot13(rnfgre vf fbzrjung pbaarpgrq jvgu n tneqra va gur tbfcry bs wbua, puncgref avargrra naq gjragl), but not by my intention.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 17):

Partial answer -- I think it is:

> Pride!

Title - A dirty limerick

> [Dirty Pride](https://peanutbutterlovesicle.bandcamp.com/track/dirty-pride-explicit) is a song in Peanut Butter Lovesicle's album: Dirty Pride

A place where the lions may roar?

> in a lion's pride

A place you attend after four?

> Unsure

The usual sense

> Sense of pride

Will shortly commence

> 2018 Gay Pridefest is occurring soon in Kansas City, MO where DLosc is from

Exploding with colors galore!

> Pride parade - goes along with previous line

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer! Unfortunately, as the difficulty with the second line indicates, it's not what I had in mind. The lion/colors overlap is pretty neat, though. +1

Comment: This works so well - can't believe it's not the right answer.

Comment: @Strawberry well the riddler is right, I can't find anything to fit the 2nd clue so it can't be it. But thanks ^_^

Answer (score 11):

Updated with help from votbear and APrough!

Answer:

> A Garden?

Title: A dirty limerick

> There's plenty of dirt in a garden

A place where the lions may roar?

> Dandelion or Red Lion Amaryllis or as votbear mentioned people sometimes put statues of lions in their gardens.

A place you attend after four?

> Kindergarten (garden?)

The usual sense

> Scents from the earth, flowers, plants, etc. (Thanks APrough - it took me a while to understand what you were getting at with the homonym tip.)

Will shortly commence

> Spring will shortly commence

Exploding with colors galore!

> With Spring comes colorful flowers

Comment: "A place you attend after four" might refer to rot13(xvaqretneqra)

Comment: Bingo! The explanations for the first two lines need some work, though. @votbear is onto something...

Comment: Regarding the first line, I remember hearing a lot about (yvba fgnghrf orvat chg va tneqraf), much more than any other animal. Can't find any specific places for it though. Maybe the rot13(Yvba Tebir Tneqra va Puvan) ?

Comment: could "sense" be a homonym?  then it makes kind of, well, sense.

Comment: Could the first line be referring to rot13(qnaqryvba)?

Comment: Hint: As indicated by the parallel sentence structure with question mark, the first clue, like the second, refers to something that isn't a rot13(tneqra) in the usual sense, but can have rot13(tneqra) in its name.

Comment: @DLosc, is the second line rot13(N trezna ovretnegra (orre tneqra) va pbzovangvba jvgu gur trezna cuenfr "xrva ovre ibe ivre", juvpu genafyngrf gb "ab orre orsber sbhe".)?

Comment: @OnlyF That's a great find! My intended solution for line 2 is what votbear said, though.

Comment: @DLosc, so which line is still wrong?

Comment: @TracyCramer Line 1.

Comment: That may be a reference to rot13("Tneqra Ebhgr" va Fbhgu Nsevpn), which advertises lion encounters..

Comment: Another hint: the place in line 1 can be found in Kansas City, or indeed in many large cities.

Answer (score 7):

> Movies

Title

> Dirty Movies

A place where the lions may roar?

> Reference to MGM

A place you attend after four?

> Go to the Movies after 4

The usual sense

> Starting to clutch at straws Sense of movement

Will shortly commence

> Was a movie about to start when you posted this?

Exploding with colors galore!

> Movies are colourful.

Comment: I really like this answer, but the plural on the first line keeps bugging me.  Yes, there's a lion's roar, but for more than half a century, it's been the one exact same lion. Uppity-votey you go anyway, of course. (And the sense is probably just "sight".)

Comment: Not the intended answer and doesn't fit all the clues, but creative! Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Answer (score 6):

Prospective answer

> Answer: Oz.

A place where the lions may roar?

> The Cowardly Lion, might roar, if he gets his courage

A place you attend after four?

> Oz has 4 witches, one for each compass direction.  The reader or watcher will also follow the story of 4 companions: Dorothy, the Tin Man, the Lion and the Scarecrow.

The usual sense
Will shortly commence

> "Follow the yellow brick road ... We're off, we're off, we're off to see the wizard!"

Exploding with colors galore!

> the Emerald City, the yellow brick road, the field of poppies... colors galore

Extra hint

> "For lines 4-5, you may wish to note when this riddle was posted and what my location is."  We are most certainly not in Kansas anymore!

Title

> I admit the weakest part of the answer but the Baum estate had to spend a lot of effort 'cease-and-desisting' nonauthorized sequels.

Comment: This would make a great answer to a riddle, but unfortunately it's not the answer to mine. I like what you've done with the location hint, though. :D

Answer (score 6):

Modified for slightly different, but related answer.  Old information is still there with strike through.

Answer:

> <s>Spring</s> Garden

Dirty limerick

> <s>in the spring you work with the</s> dirt in the garden/yard/flower garden

and

> also refers to all the mud everywhere from the spring rains

A place where the lions may roar?

> <s>Dandelions roar all over the yard</s> Zoological garden (aka zoo) - Only place to see (and hear) actual lions around here.

A place you attend after four?

> <s>Tend your yard/garden after work / after 4:00  from @Tracycramer</s> Kinder*garden* correct spelling kindergarten -- where you go to school at four years old.

<s>or,</s>

> **Alternative:** the four seasons (spring, summer fall, winter).. after the fourth one (winter) we come back around to spring.  I actually like this one better now

The usual sense

> <s>Sense of smell - smelling the flowers that come with spring</s>Sense of wonder at the beauty of nature with all the flowers; also: sight - looking at the flowers.

Will shortly commence

Exploding with colors galore!

> First day of spring...  flowers will be blooming soon... (actually my crocus already are:) )

Comment: Someone already suggested "garden" as the solution ...

Comment: Not quite it, I'm afraid. If I were to nitpick, I'd point out that "sense of smell" doesn't fit with "colors," and "time of year" isn't a "place." I like what you've done with the 'lions, though. (Our crocuses are out too!)

Comment: (Previous versions are always retained as part of the [edit history](/posts/62380/revisions) - there's no need to retain the original, unless the original version is for some reason important to or referenced by the update.  Feel free to clean up your answer to remove the original attempt.  But as noted, your new attempt is largely duplicative of an earlier answer; at this point, deleting it altogether may be best, unless you can improve upon the other answer sufficiently to make yours a more complete and relevant solution to the riddle.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I'm onto something, but maybe it has something to do with

> Plays?

A place where the lions may roar?

> The Lion King, which was playing in KC MO (the OP's given location), starting at 7:30 PM on the posting date. (Hint was *when* and *where*)

A place you attend after four?

> it is typical to attend plays after four...

The usual sense/Will shortly commence

> The show was possibly in intermission shortly before the question was posted.

Exploding with colors galore!

> The Lion King is a *very* colorful show.

I'm not sure why this is a dirty limerick, though.

Comment: Not the intended answer and doesn't fit all the clues, but +1. I'm finding out a lot about what's happening in Kansas City from these answers!

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> Stadium

Title:

> A stadium is usually dirty from all of the litter left by fans

A place where the lions may roar?

> A reference to the victory of a sports club with lions in their name, say Detroit Lions?

A place you attend after four?

> The match would most likely take place in the evening

The usual sense

> Pride/excitement/fanfare/loyalty for a team

Will shortly commence

> I'm not from the North America and I don't keep track of sporting events, but surely there must be a big game soon?

Exploding with colors galore!

> Could this be fireworks?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> May

Dirty Limerick

> Unsure

A place where lions may roar

> Old saying: In like a lion, out like a lamb

A place you attend after four

> May is the fifth month, so you attend it after April, the 4th month

The usual sense

> Sense of smell (flowers bloom in May, see below)

Will shortly commence

> It's almost the end of March at the time this was posted, so May is only about a month away

Exploding with colors galore

> Another old saying: April showers bring May flowers, so May is the month where flowers bloom

Comment: I think the old saying you quoted for line 1 applies to March, not May

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> The Kauffman, a.k.a. The K

Title: A Dirty Limerick

> The Kauffman is famously dirty, a fact that came to light in a national way during the World Series - for instance, “cockroaches in vending areas, mouse feces on the same tray as pizza dough, sinks where employees were supposed to wash their hands being blocked by boxes or trash.”

A place where the lions may roar?

> Sluggerrrrr, the Mascot, a Lion, and the roars he inspires.

A place you attend after four?

> When the ball game starts.

The usual sense

> IE Midwestern workaday sobriety

Will shortly commence
Exploding with colors galore!

> Will soon transform into drunken, colorful revelry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Paige Meinke is onto something with there answer to their answer to the first line, though I feel that it is a very open answer.

Answer:

> Term(s)

A place where the lions may roar?

> A Pride of Lions

A place you attend after four?

> A School of fish

The usual sense

> A Cowardice of curs

Will shortly commence

> Term is a new school term about to commence in Kansas?

Exploding with colors galore!

> A Colour Term